# Biztalk:How can we split flat file into multiple files of some defined size messages

Tags: biztalk

I have flatfile at receive end & want to split it into multiple files of some fixed message size say 1000 messages per file. How we can implement it in receive pipeline?

Comment: This question is rather broad and there are plenty of examples of how to split flat files on the internet with BizTalk.  Have you tried any of those and struck a specific problem?  Is it keeping them in batches of 1000 that is the issue?  If so can you give us a sample file, the XSD file(s) you've created so far and your pipeline configuration so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm able to split now the file in batches,needed to implement Disassembler component but was unable to pass batching size as configurable from property bag. So having question now, can we load field in property bag & pass it to Disassemble  component.I checked with execute method of IComponent interface & there we can pass it but not sure on disassembler component.

Comment: Have you tried using the BizTalk Server Pipeline Component Wizard?  https://btsplcw.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I understand the scenario you are asking about.

The way to address this, given the Receive Port requirement, is with a custom Disassembler component that can manage the rebatching internally.

You can wrap FFDasmComp (that is the Flat File Disassembler) so it does most of the work.

There is no way to do this with out of the box tooling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I'm able to split now the file in batches,needed to implement Disassembler component but was unable to pass batching size as configurable from property bag. So having question now, can we load field in property bag & pass it to Disassemble  component.I checked with execute method of IComponent interface & there we can pass it but not sure on disassembler component.